# Dialogflow : how to receive an image in Hangouts? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, dialogflow-es, chatbot, dialogflow-es-fulfillment, google-hangouts

I am trying to build a chatbot in Dialogflow connected to Hangouts. I am working on receiving files such as images.

I have found a [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7YA91gv9RpU&list=PLj-LOoBjYq6fXw1GSO1Q6ffoV-DZ7UFHQ&index=10) about "How to receive image, audio, video and rich media on a WhatsApp chatbot (via dialogflow)". I have followed the instructions but something is not working.

This is my index.js code (Inline editor - Fulfillment):

```
'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const {Card, Suggestion} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');

process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:debug';

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
  console.log('Dialogflow Request headers: ' + JSON.stringify(request.headers));
  console.log('Dialogflow Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(request.body));

function welcome(agent) {
    agent.add(`¡Bienvenido a mi chatbot! ¿Quieres subir un código QR?`);
  }

  function fallback(agent) {
    agent.add(`Lo siento, no te he entendido.`);
    agent.add(`¿Podrías repetir otra vez?`);
  }

function mediaHandler(agent) {
 exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
 let originalRequest = request.body.originalDetectIntentRequest; 
 agent.add(`Aquí tengo el archivo que me has mandado, gracias.` +  originalRequest.payload.data.MediaUrl0);
  });
  }

let intentMap = new Map();
  intentMap.set('Default Welcome Intent', welcome);
  intentMap.set('Default Fallback Intent', fallback);
  intentMap.set('Hangouts Media - fallback', mediaHandler);

  agent.handleRequest(intentMap);});
```

These are my intents:

[Intents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OImAg.png)

And this is the error:

> Error: No handler for requested intent at WebhookClient.handleRequest (/srv/node_modules/dialogflow-fulfillment/src/dialogflow-fulfillment.js:327:29) at exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment.functions.https.onRequest (/srv/index.js:94:9) at cloudFunction (/srv/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/https.js:26:47) at /worker/worker.js:783:7 at /worker/worker.js:766:11 at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:132:7) at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:219:9)

Finally, this is the package.json:

```
{
  "name": "dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment",
  "description": "This is the default fulfillment for a Dialogflow agents using Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "license": "Apache Version 2.0",
  "author": "Google Inc.",
  "engines": {
    "node": "^6.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "firebase serve --only functions:dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions:dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "actions-on-google": "^2.0.0-alpha.4",
    "firebase-admin": "^4.2.1",
    "firebase-functions": "^0.5.7",
    "dialogflow": "^0.1.0",
    "dialogflow-fulfillment": "^0.6.1",
    "qrcode-decoder": "^0.1.2",
    "xmlhttprequest": "^1.8.0",
    "filereader": "^0.10.3"

  }
}
```

Do you know how I can fix my error?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: You are getting this error because an intent is calling your fulfillment, but the intentMap does not have a function mapped to the intent name. When exactly are you getting the error? From your image I can see that the Hangouts Media Intent doesn't have a handler, is this as it should be?

Comment: ```originalRequest.payload.data.MediaUrl0```
this code will work only for Whatsapp. This will not work for receiving media from Hangout or any messaging channel.